# npm start error angularjs(frontend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

> $ npm start
>
> > angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart C:\wamp64\www\myapplication
> >     npm install
>
> npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
>
> > angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall C:\wamp64\www\myapplication
> >     bower install
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3
>   (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> up to date in 78.888s
>
> > angular-seed@0.0.0 start C:\wamp64\www\myapplication
> >     http-server -a localhost -p 8001 -c-1 ./app
>
> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8001
>       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
>       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
>       at listen (net.js:1298:10)
>       at net.js:1408:9
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0
>   start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8001 -c-1 ./app` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-01-07T16_08_23_941Z-debug.log

i had this error when i run npm start frontend(angularjs)and in the symfony is run correctly can someone have a idea how can i solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another process is already listening on port `8001`. You are either trying to start your server twice, or there is another server/application which uses that port. The solution is to change the port or kill the process which listens on the same port.